# Complex string parsing issues

Tags: regex, string, parsing

I have the following PHP string:

> "{'blah':1178,'blah':0,'blah':260,'blah':0,'needWrapper':
>
> > {'NEED':'TEXTNEED','NEED':'TEXTNEED'}, 'blah':'blah'}"

EDIT: I broke it up to hopefully make it more readable

I need to get the "NEED: TEXTNEED" and "NEED: TEXTNEED" substrings from that. I feel like there's a good way to do that with regex's or using explode or something but I can't quite piece together an elegant/working solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are both `NEED`s the same string? Otherwise, this is perfect JSON. (ok, maybe except the quotes - jdi is right there)

Comment: this looks like a JSON string. Which programming language/script you are using? Probably u can use one of JSON api compatible to ur language to parse the above.

Comment: This is a PHP string, how would I use this with JSON parsing in PHP??

Comment: Actually, when I tried to JSON_decode this it returned "NULL"...something must be wrong with that. Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace the single quotes with double quotes, it can be parsed with json:

```
import json

s = "{'blah':1178,'blah':0,'blah':260,'blah':0,'needWrapper':{'NEED':'TEXTNEED','NEED':'TEXTNEED'}, 'blah':'blah'}"

print json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
# {u'blah': u'blah', u'needWrapper': {u'NEED': u'TEXTNEED'}}
```

Now you can just access the objects.

If the source is coming from php, it should be able to produce valid JSON with double quoted objects: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Of course, this will fail miserably if there are unescaped double quotes in the string: `{'a':'"Hello"'}`. It also shouldn't work if both keys are the same (you only have one is the result), although that just might be a poor example by the OP.

Comment: @Kobi: It has to be a poor example because there is no reason for duplicate keys. This is an extremely limited example by the OP so all I can do is address what he provided.

Comment: yeah keys are not the same. Sorry.

Comment: @Kobi: Also, single quotes in a JSON string is not valid (does not pass a json lint) so I think its less a responsibility of the python side to try and handle the cases, and more on the source to be producing valid JSON.

Comment: So I'm actually trying to call json_decode on this string:

{"playerId":1178,"percentChange":0.1,"averageDraftPosition":260,"percentOwned":0.1,"mostRecentNews":{"news":"Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians' official Twitter feed reports.","spin":"He'll replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season.","date":"Mon May 14"},"fullName":"Jeremy Accardo"}

But when I do, it still returns null. No single quotes anymore, am I still missing something?

Comment: @sfgiants2010: We are talking about the PHP side now? You might need to update your question with more details. Its too much for this comment area. Or make another question with a PHP specific problem and tag it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a different question that is more specific and includes the actual string. This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630834/php-complex-string-parse-jsonable

Comment: @sfgiants2010: ok cool. And if this answer solved your python json question, don't for get to accept it to close this specific issue down.