# PHP Complex String Parse, JSON'able?

Tags: php, json, string, parsing

So I have the following PHP string:

```
$output = {"playerId":1178,"percentChange":0.1,"averageDraftPosition":260,"percentOwned":0.1,"mostRecentNews":{"news":"Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians' official Twitter feed reports.","spin":"He'll replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season.","date":"Mon May 14"},"fullName":"Jeremy Accardo"}
```

What I need is: "Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians' official Twitter feed reports." and "He'll replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season." as substrings. But I can't seem to figure out the best and most elegant way to do that. I tried to JSON_decode the string but I get nothing returned. Any ideas? (I am using PHP)

Comment: can you give us a snippet of the code you are using to parse it? also, notice that json_decode has a second variable that lets you choose if it's an array or an object.

Comment: @sfgiants2010 your json data contains many unescaped single quote, i have fixed it, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have few unescaped string, that is causing the error. a simple formatting could have saved you the time.

```
$output = '{
    "playerId":1178,
    "percentChange":0.1,
    "averageDraftPosition":260,
    "percentOwned":0.1,
    "mostRecentNews": {
        "news":"Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians official Twitter feed reports",
        "spin":"Hell replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season.",
        "date":"Mon May 14"
    },
    "fullName":"Jeremy Accardo"
}';
$json = json_decode($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a `string`. Try like this:

```
$output = '{"playerId":1178,"percentChange":0.1,"averageDraftPosition":260,"percentOwned":0.1,"mostRecentNews":{"news":"Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians\' official Twitter feed reports.","spin":"He\'ll replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season.","date":"Mon May 14"},"fullName":"Jeremy Accardo"}';

$object = json_decode($output);
$array = json_decode($output, true);
$string = json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$output = '{"playerId":1178,"percentChange":0.1,"averageDraftPosition":260,"percentOwned":0.1,"mostRecentNews":{"news":"Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians\' official Twitter feed reports.","spin":"He\'ll replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season.","date":"Mon May 14"},"fullName":"Jeremy Accardo"}';

$array = json_decode($output, true);

echo $array['mostRecentNews']['news'];
echo $array['mostRecentNews']['spin'];
```

Answer (score 0):

json_encode with with only UTF8. are you using allthings with utf8? and you hava synstax error. if you define json variable manually it could be like this;

```
<?php
$output=<<<JSONSTR
{"playerId":1178,"percentChange":0.1,"averageDraftPosition":260,"percentOwned":0.1,"mostRecentNews":{"news":"Accardo was called up from Columbus on Monday, the Indians' official Twitter feed reports.","spin":"He'll replace Dan Wheeler on the active roster after carrying a 2.76 ERA over 13 appearances with the Clippers to start the season.","date":"Mon May 14"},"fullName":"Jeremy Accardo"}
JSONSTR;
$variable = json_decode($output);
var_dump($variable);
?>
```